# Using LocalServiceUtils in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

we are starting our first Liferay 7 project and I already got stuck.

I would like to create a portlet which reads the Data from the DDMContent Table.
Luckily there is the DDMContentLocalServiceUtil.

I am struggeling on how to actually use it.

I added it to the build.gradile file like this:

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.api", version: "3.1.0"
```

I added it to the bnd.bnd file like this :

```
Import-Package: com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.api;version=3.1.0
```

And then I included in my portlet class like this:

```
@Reference
    public void setContentLocalServiceUtil(DDMContentLocalServiceUtil contentLocalServiceUtil) {
        this.contentLocalServiceUtil = contentLocalServiceUtil;
    }
```

The portlet compiles and starts to deploy but I never get to the point where I can actually use it because it is never fully deployed.
There is no Exception and there is no hint on what I did wrong.

Is my version number correct ?
Do I need to add it to the bnd.bnd file ?
Who can help me out ?

Best regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You should use

```
Import-Package: *
```

and let BND resolve that for you based on the jar file you are compiling against (the one you have in Gradle's dependencies)

2) Do not import the `<Name>LocalServiceUtil` classes. Those are not OSGi services. Use `<Name>LocalService` instead. Those are the interfaces that define the contracts. In your case it should be:

```
@Reference
public void setContentLocalService(DDMContentLocalService contentLocalService) {
```

3) If your bundle still does not start properly, connect to gogo shell (`telnet localhost 11311`) and check it's status. Use `diag` command or simply try to manually start it with `start <bundleId>` and the framework will tell you if something is wrong with it.